# Any possible way to develop 3d earth map application for iphone?

Tags: iphone, dictionary, google-earth, virtual-earth

I need to develop an iPhone 3d map application similar to virtual earth or google earth. The application will have images overlay above the 3d map, like clouds or location pin. Anyone has any ideas on that?

Regards

Edit:
Try to make the phrase not vague this time:

As far as I know, google earth and microsoft virtual earth api (3d) are not supported for any iOS devices.
In stead of redoing everything from ground up using OpenGL ES, which is the only way to do 3d in iOS devices with hardware acceleration, I want to develop a map application with established map services, such as google map. However, the map will be in 3d.

Of course, I can make a simple 3d earth using openGL ES with hardcore geo location similar to living earth HD, but I try to avoid that.

Comment: Far too vague as currently phrased.

Comment: Vague indeed. OpenGL perhaps.

Comment: Agreed.  Pick out a particular aspect of this that you are having trouble with and we'd be glad to answer that.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at WhirlyGlobe library : http://code.google.com/p/whirlyglobe/

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out eeGeo's iOS and Android SDK, which offers vector-based 3D maps for all of the USA, Canada and UK.

Comment: This might need some improvement to fit the Original Post's question and add some value to the solution Leo is asking. You may want to re-read the StackOverflow Netiquette Do-s & Don't-s and re-edit your post to meet the set Community rules.